# Scalar self-energy in $\mathcal{N}=4$ SYM in position space

Tags: quantum-field-theory, supersymmetry, wick-theorem, self-energy

In this paper ([BMN Correlators and Operator Mixing in $\mathcal{N}=4$ Super Yang-Mills Theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0208178), 2002), the authors give the following expression for the self-energy of the scalar propagator in $\mathcal{N}=4$ Super Yang-Mills (SYM) in Euclidean space (p.26):

$$\left. \left\langle Z^a (x_1) \bar{Z}^b (x_2) \right\rangle \right|_\text{1-loop} = - \frac{1}{2} g^4 N\ \text{Tr}\ T^{\tilde{a}} T^{\tilde{b}} (Y_{112} + Y_{122}) \tag{1}$$

with

$$Y_{123} := \int d^4 x_4 I_{14} I_{24} I_{34} \quad, \quad  I_{12} := \frac{1}{(2\pi)^2 (x_1 - x_2)^2} \tag{2}$$

Furthermore, they indicate:

> (...) (T)he momentum space representation $\int d^4k/(2\pi)^4 p^2 k^2 (p-k)^2$ of $Y_{112}$ is just the sum of contributions from the
>   scalar-gluon loop and the scalar tadpole.

Now I would like to derive the expression given in $(1)$, but directly in position space, and in particular reproduce the last part of the claim quoted above. The relevant parts of the action are (see eq. (A.3) p.24 in paper):

$$\frac{1}{g^2} \text{Tr}\ D_\mu \phi_i D_\mu \phi_i \quad, \quad -\frac{1}{2 g^2} \text{Tr} \left[\phi_i,\phi_j \right]\left[\phi_i,\phi_j \right] \tag{3}$$

with $D_\mu \phi := \partial_\mu \phi_i - i \left[A_\mu, \phi_i \right]$.

For the scalar-gluon loop, I get:

$$\Sigma_1 = \frac{1}{2} \left(- \frac{i}{g^2} \right)^2 \text{Tr}\ T^{a'} \left[T^{b'},T^{c'} \right] \text{Tr}\ T^{d'} \left[T^{e'},T^{f'} \right] \int d^4 x_{34} \left\langle \phi_1^{i,a} \phi_2^{j,b} \partial_\mu \phi_3^{k,a'} A_{3,\mu}^{b'} \phi_3^{k,c'} \partial_\nu \phi_4^{l,d'} A_{4,\nu}^{e'} \phi_4^{l,f'} \right\rangle \tag{4}$$

where $d^4 x_{34} := d^4 x_3 d^4 x_4$, $\phi_1 := \phi(x_1)$, and where the factor $1/2$ comes from the expansion of $e^{-S}$. From the Wick contractions, I get $4$ different terms with a symmetry factor of $2$ due to the exchange $3 \leftrightarrow 4$. Doing all the contractions, and integrating by parts each term so that they all look the same, I find:

$$\Sigma_1 = - \frac{1}{2} g^4 N \delta_{ij} \text{Tr}\ T^{\tilde{a}} T^{\tilde{b}} \int d^4 x_{34} I_{13} I_{24} \left\lbrace 5 I_{34} \partial_3^2 I_{34} + 4 (\partial_{3,\mu} I_{34})^2 \right\rbrace \tag{5}$$

Using Green's eq. $\partial_3^2 I_{34} = - \delta(x_3 - x_4)$, I can kill one integral in the first term. In the second term, I can just compute the derivative and I find that $(\partial_{3,\mu} I_{34})^2 = 4 (2\pi)^2 I_{34}^3$. This gives me:

$$\Sigma_1 = - \frac{1}{2} g^4 N \delta_{ij} \text{Tr}\ T^{\tilde{a}} T^{\tilde{b}} \left\lbrace -5 \int d^4 x_3 I_{13} I_{23} I_{33} + 16 (2\pi)^2 \int d^4 x_3 I_{13} \int d^4 x_4 I_{24} I_{34}^3 \right\rbrace \tag{6}$$

The remaining $x_4$-integral can be done in dimensional regularization, but it turns out to be finite:

$$\int d^4 x_4 I_{24} I_{34}^3 = - \frac{\pi^2}{16\pi^4} I_{23}^2 \tag{7}$$

All in all I get:

$$\Sigma_1 = - \frac{1}{2} g^4 N \delta_{ij} \text{Tr}\ T^{\tilde{a}} T^{\tilde{b}} \left\lbrace -5 \int d^4 x_3 I_{13} I_{23} I_{33} - 4 Y_{122} \right\rbrace \tag{8}$$

Fortunately, the scalar tadpole is a lot easier to compute:

$$\begin{align} \Sigma_2 &= - \left( - \frac{1}{2g^2} \right) \text{Tr} \left[T^c, T^d \right] \left[T^e, T^f \right] \int d^4 x_3 \left\langle \phi_1^{i,a} \phi_2^{j,b} \phi_3^{k,c} \phi_3^{l,d} \phi_3^{k,e} \phi_3^{l,f} \right\rangle \\ &= 2 g^4 \text{Tr} \left[T^a, T^c \right] \left[T^b, T^c \right] \delta_{ij} \left(\delta_{kk} - 1 \right) \int d^4 x_3 I_{13} I_{23} I_{33} \\ &= -10 g^4 N \text{Tr}\ T^\tilde{a} T^\tilde{b} \delta_{ij} \int d^4 x_3 I_{13} I_{23} I_{33} \tag{9} \end{align}$$

where I found a symmetry factor of $4$ and $\delta_{kk} = 6$, and where the first minus sign comes from the expansion of $e^{-S}$.

Now I would like to add eq. $(8)$ and eq. $(9)$ and see the integral with the $I_{33}$ cancel. Both have a factor $5$, so that's good, but the numerical prefactors don't match. The sign of the term with $Y_{122}$ also doesn't match the expression given in $(1)$. So it seems like eq. $(8)$ should be $-4$ times smaller, and thus eq. $(9)$ should be $-16$ times smaller. I suspect that I make a mistake reading the Feynman rules in position space, or with counting the symmetry factors.

Where is the mistake?

**EDIT**:

I may have found **one mistake** in $(4)$: the first vertex given in $(3)$ produces 2 times the same term, hence I think that I should have $(-2i/g^2)^2$ in $(4)$ instead of $(-i/g^2)^2$. This makes the final result in $(8)$ $4$ times larger, and hence now both the unwanted part of eq. $(8)$ cancels with eq. $(9)$! The factor $-16$ remains though, which is not there in eq. $(1)$. I am still confused why this is the case.

**EDIT 2**:

In the paper, they go on and compute the $4$-point function (see (A.9)). They have a prefactor $-1/8$, and reproducing the computation as I have done here, I get again this discrepancy of my result being $-16$ bigger! I still can't figure it out, it could have something to do with normalization but I take the action as given in the paper.

Comment: Note that I tested my method for Wick contractions and symmetry factors against the $\phi^4$ example given in Peskin p.91, and I find the right result in that case. That is why I decided to post this question.