# Am I reading this Feynman diagram in $\mathcal{N}=4$ SYM right?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, supersymmetry, feynman-diagrams, wick-theorem

I would like to find the expression corresponding to the scalar-gluon sunset diagram in position space, for Euclidean $\mathcal{N}=4$ Super Yang-Mills theory. The diagram is the following:

[image]

where the solid lines are scalar fields, and the wavy line is a gluon as always. The relevant part of the action is the following:

$$\frac{1}{2 g^2} \int d^4 x \left(\partial_\mu \phi^{i,a} + f^{abc} A_\mu^b \phi^{i,c} \right)^2 \tag{1}$$

The full action can be found in this paper ([Wilson Loops in $\mathcal{N}=4$ SYM](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0003055), 2000). Reading the diagram in position space, I find:

$$\Sigma = \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{1}{g^2} \right)^2 f^{a'b'c'}f^{d'e'f'} \int d^4 x_3\ d^4x_4 \left\langle \phi_1^{i,a} \phi_2^{j,b} \partial_\mu \phi_3^{i',a'} A_{3\mu}^{b'} \phi_3^{i',c'} \partial_\nu \phi_4^{j',d'} A_{4\nu}^{e'} \phi_4^{j',f'} \right\rangle \tag{2}$$

with $\phi_1 := \phi(x_1)$. The first $1/2$ factor comes from the expansion of $e^{-S}$. The second factor comes from the vertex, and there is no $2$ in the denominator because the square in $(1)$ produces a $2$ in the denominator.

Doing the Wick contractions give me a factor $2$ for the $3 \leftrightarrow 4$ symmetry, and I get $4$ different contractions. Is that all correct up to that point?

I am asking because at the end of the day I find:

$$\Sigma = 4 g^4 N \delta^{ab} \delta_{ij} Y_{122} + 5 g^4 N \delta^{ab} \delta_{ij} \int d^4 x_3\ I_{13} I_{23} I_{33} \tag{3}$$

with

$$Y_{123} := \int d^4 x_4 I_{14} I_{24} I_{34} \tag{4}$$

and the logarithmic divergence of $(3)$ does not match what is given in the paper I linked above by a factor of $-2$. I have checked my computations about a dozen times, so I figure the mistake is probably hiding in the way I read the diagram.

(note that this question is related to [that one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/537488/scalar-self-energy-in-mathcaln-4-sym-in-position-space), which I realize may have been too dense for getting an answer)